# How do you deal with "Many Names for 1 Person"?

Tags: data-structures

One of the most common problems I run into when creating any information system is the fact that people go by so many different  names. Someone named "Bill Smith" may go by "Will Smith","William Smith", "Smith, Will", etc... If say, I wanted to write an application to link blog posts to authors, I would have to account for all those names.

My question is: What approaches do you take to keep consistent data throughout your application. How do you structure your database so that you can refer to a single identifier to locate all those names? What UI approaches do you take make sure that people enter in names in a consistent manner?

Comment: You should accept an answer for this question. It's been several months.

Answer (score 17):

As long as you have a unique id for each user (which is *not* their name) you can have a table that maps name variations to a unique id, and then associate each post with that unique ID.

```
(Table mapping names to UIDs)

Name        UID

Robert S    123456
Bob S       123456
Bert S      123456
Darren      987654
```

```
(Table with post information, including author's UID)

Title     Author  ...

Post 1    123456
Post 2    123456
Post 3    987654
```

```
(Table with author information)

UID     Preferred Name   Webpage                ...

123456  Robert Smith     http://www.robert.com
987654  Darren Jones     http://www.jones.com
```

Comment: Definitely. If someone gets married or changes their name, you probably want them to be able to just change their name on your website themselves, w/o disrupting the continuity of the data associated with their user ID.

Comment: I think I would make "preferred name" be a flag on the table that maps names to UIDs, as it logically will be a name in that list, and thus denormalized.  That's a pretty minor gripe though.  Other than that, the same solution I would have come up with.  +1

Comment: @rmeador Yeah, it looks like Jonathan mentioned something like the flag in his post; It seems pretty logical.

Answer (score 10):

It's probably a good idea to accept only one name from your user, and allow them a "nickname" or a "public name". That gives them the freedom to have a legal name, perhaps for mailing or billing, and a public-viewable name for interaction on your site.

Beyond that, I don't think I would allow my users to have multiple names, unless my system required it. If I did, I'd split it up into two tables:

- **Users:**

  - userid *(ex: 1821)*
- **UserNames:**

  - userid *(ex: 1821)*
  - firstName *(ex: Jonathan)*
  - lastName *(ex: Sampson)*

In addition, you could add a field in the `usernames` table called '`isPrimary`'. This would be a boolean value that will tell you which name to treat as the primary name for the user. This is similar to how wikipedia store a history of data/changes. They keep all, but mark which is "active", or in your case "primary".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are trying to use their name as a primary key or UID. This is the wrong way to go. You should have a seperate UID as the primary key, then the name can be whatever you want, and you can even have a list of alternate names.

Comment: Database purists (Like Joe Celko) would argue otherwise.  Table keys should be "Natural" keys.  Creating an artificial ID would be considered the wrong way to go.  This is, however, a pretty common way to handle the problem, but it's not a matter of "right or wrong".  You're too black and white.

Comment: @Mystere Man: Arguing that you should use a field like a name that can change or be a duplicate as a primary key or UID is pretty stupid. I cannot even imagine how you got this idea, but please don't spread these kinds of ideas.

Comment: a natural key for a table key would be nice, but not if that natural key is going to violate the very fundamentals of what a UID is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the first 3 posts on how to structure your schema.

In regards to the UI I would allow a field for the persons legal first,middle and lastname which should change very rarely.

Then allow nickname(s) depending on your application requirements.

Having their full legal name can come in handy for billing/financial/HR situations too.

Comment: Sometimes people change their legal name for other reasons than marriage.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem happens when you have multiple applications, and each one has their own schema for user information.  The billing system might have "Will Smith"; the payroll system might have "William Smith"; the claims system might have "Willie X. Smith".  All are really the same person.  What do you do?  It's a huge issue for stovepipe, legacy apps.

Answer (score 1):

You could always make a AKA table, where you could have the prefer name to AKA name. So if someone uses the name Bill, you can always replace it with William.

I have never personally used this concept for names, but I do support a project that does something similar with Movie Titles, which can varied for different countries.